# JQuery numeric don't focus on next element after "Enter"

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, numeric

I have a many input element on my form.
My custom.js is:

```
$(document).ready
(
    function () {
        $("#sum").autoNumeric('init', {aSep: ' ', aDec: '.', lZero: 'deny', mDec: '2', vMin: '0', vMax: '9990000000'});
    }
);

$.keyHandler = function (event, object) {
    var enter = 13;
    if (enter == event.keyCode) {
        var inputs = {
            'date': 'sum'
            , 'sum': 'next'
        };
        if (object != null) {
            var next = inputs[object.name];
            if (next) {
                var elem = document.getElementsByName(next)[0];
                if ($(elem).is(':disabled') == false) {
                    $(elem).focus();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My JSP page is:

```
<td>Сумма:</td>
<td><form:input path="sum" size="27" onkeydown="return $.keyHandler(event, this);"/></td>
```

Then I enter "ENTER" (not on sum field) then focus is changed to next field.
Then in sum field I enter "ENTER" then focus don't changed.
Then I comment **autoNumeric**, then focus is changed.
Help! What the problem?

Comment: `autoNumeric` causes the element to lose focus?

Comment: @Mouser Yes, why and how can i fix this?

Comment: Try to change your keyhandler to keyup.